# How do I provide this function's different props based on button's click event?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, components

I am attempting to reuse a function to open a modal in Ionic 4. These both work, while separate, but would prefer to combine based on their independent arguments to change the title in the modal that appears.

This does not compile, but shows what I am essentially trying to achieve:

```
async openModal(edit, add) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalComponent,
        componentProps: {
            if (edit) {
                'title': 'Edit Firehouse'
            else if (add) {
                'title': 'Add Firehouse'
            },
            'firehouseShow': true
        }
    });
    return await modal.present();
}
```

Here is what is currently in place and does compile even with the error:

> 'Duplicate function implementation.'

```
async openModal(edit) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalComponent,
        componentProps: {
            'title': 'Edit Firehouse',
            'firehouseShow': true
        }
    });
    return await modal.present();
}

async openModal(add) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalComponent,
        componentProps: {
            'title': 'AddFirehouse',
            'firehouseShow': true
        }
    });
    return await modal.present();
}
```

These functions are being called via Angular button click event:

```
<ion-button (click)="openModal(edit)">Edit</ion-button>
<ion-button (click)="openModal(add)">Add</ion-button>
```

I would prefer to reuse this function, especially since it's only being called on a single page (at a time). It does however dynamically change what is displayed within the modal and what data is populated, or not populated per click event. For instance the 'add' click event will not retrieve any data, but the 'edit' would.

Comment: Something to try: `'title': edit ? 'Edit Firehouse' : 'Add Firehouse'`??

Comment: tried this, both resulted in 'Add Firehouse'

Comment: if both result in Add Firehouse then `edit` is never `true`

Comment: well how are you calling it??

Comment: angular button click event

Comment: so show it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one wouldn't work too even duplicated function issue had been solved because both function do the same thing.

Consinder passing the `componentProps` as parameter.

```ts
async openModal(componentProps) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalComponent,
        componentProps
    });
    return await modal.present();
}
```

And when call a function :

```ts
openModal({
 'title': 'Edit Firehouse',
 'firehouseShow': true
})
// or
openModal({
 'title': 'Add Firehouse',
 'firehouseShow': true
})
```

**Update**

If you want to get only title as parameter, set a title when create an object.

```
async openModal(title) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalComponent,
        componentProps : {
          'title': title,
          'firehouseShow': true
      }
    });
    return await modal.present();
}
```

And then:

```ts
openModal('Edit Firehouse')
// or
openModal('Add Firehouse')
```

Comment: thank you, this took care of it. Is there a way to keep similar props with the function instead of the call? For instance the 'firehouseShow: true

Comment: If i understood correctly, it can be done with make a object in the function. I've updated post.